# How to create long format data frame (specific example)

Tags: r

I wonder how i could transform this data frame:

[image]

To this kind of data frame:

[image]

I have tried it with melt functions but I can not get a correct solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please do not post images of data. copy-paste the output of `dput(mydata)` instead.

Comment: Try `tidyr`'s `pivot_longer` function: `pivot_longer(your_data, c("grsplet", "power", "hedonism"))`.